# What is the correct syntax for calling an overloaded method using 'this()' in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, overloading

I may have this wrong, but I've seen the way of creating an overloaded method that calls itself in the definition. It's something like:

```
public void myFunction(int a, int b)
{
    //Some code here
}

public void myFunction(int a) : this (a, 10)
{ }
```

This is not the correct syntax, I know, but I can't find the correct syntax anywhere for some reason. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: The `this()` syntax can only be used for constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing constructor syntax for method  syntax.  The only way to do that for a method is the obvious:

```
public void myFunction(int a, int b) 
{ 
    //Some code here 
} 

public void myFunction(int a) 
{ 
     myFunction(a, 10) ;
}
```

although as of C#4, you can use a optional parameters:

```
public void myFunction(int a, int b = 10) 
{ 
    //Some code here 
}
```

What you wrote is close to right for constructors:

```
public class myClass
{

    public myClass(int a, int b)
    {
        //Some code here
    }

    public myClass(int a) : this (a, 10)
    { }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just do this:

```
public void myFunction(int a, int b)
{
    //Some code here
}

public void myFunction(int a) 
{
    myFunction(a, 10)
}
```

You're confusing overloading with overriding.  You can call a base constructor from an derived class like this:

```
public MyConstructor(int foo) 
   :base (10)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseClass {
     public virtual void SomeFunction(int a, int b) {}
}

public class Derived : BaseClass {
     public override SomeFunction(int a, int b) {
          base.SomeFunction(a, b * 10);
     }
}
```

Comment: The question is about overloading, not overriding.